# Cannot use another class in TypeScript for an electron project

Tags: typescript, electron

So I get a myriad of errors using classes in my electron application that uses typescript.

First I tried having the window created in a different class. Heres the code

```js
/** 
 * Entry point of program
 * 
*/

const { MainPage } = require('./ui/mainpage.ts');


let menu = new MainPage();
menu.startApplication();
```

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require ('electron');
 
export class MainPage {

    /**
     * Creates the main menu, using value from constructor
     * 
     */
    startApplication() {
        let mainWindow;

        app.on('ready', () => {
            mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ 
               // fields for my application
            });
            mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/ui/views/index.html`);
        });
    }
}
```

The problem I get says unexpected token 'export' where I use the export key on my MainPage class

Now I decided just to build the window in the main class, bad idea since I'm gonna eventually need to use other classes. Heres the code I have now

```js
/** 
 * Entry point of program
 * 
 * @author 
*/

const { MainPage } = require("./logic/mainpage");
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require ('electron');


let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ 
      // fields again for my project
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/ui/html/index.html`);
});
```

```js
export class MainPage {

    /**
     * Creates the main menu, using value from constructor
     * 
     */
    loadPdfs() {
        console.log('Im in here');
    }
}
```

Now the problem I get is Cannot find module './logic/mainpage'
I have tried messing with the tsconfig changing it to es5, es6, commonjs, esnext, etc and nothing works. I would prefer a fix to my first issue, since I'd prefer to have the window be built inside of that class.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "CommonJS",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

Heres my package.json

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "pupil",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src\\app.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json",
    "start": "npm run build && electron ."
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "keywords": [

  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^24.1.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
}
```

Edit: I switched back trying to where the window is loaded from a different class and I changed the require to an import in `app.ts` and now I get cannot use import statement outside a module.

Heres the full error

```
import  {MainApplication} from './ui/mainpage';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)  
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1156:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1197:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1296:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:937:12)
    at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13330)
    at loadApplicationPackage (A:\github projects\pupil\Pupil\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:121:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (A:\github projects\pupil\Pupil\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:233:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
[15756:0429/004122.496:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(677)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for wpad failed:
----- Certificate i=0 (CN=self-signedKey,O=Sagemcom Ca,C=FR) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found
```

Comment: try setting moduleResolution to node in your tsconfig.json file

Comment: Doesn't fix it, just edited my question with my tsconfig